# RoboMaster Plaintext Protocol Not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to control my RoboMaster EP Core robot using the plaintext protocol as described in the [documentation](https://robomaster-dev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text_sdk/intro.html), however it does not seem to work. Here is what I've done:

- Connected my laptop to the robot's WIFI (i.e.. direct connection).
- Created the Python script using the example code from the docs.

When I ran the script in Python 3.9 (Microsoft Store version), I entered `command` to put the robot into SDK mode (as described in the documentation), and then I tried to get the battery level by using `robot battery ?`, but it never gave a response. I also tried changing the LED colours by using `led control comp all r 255 g 0 b 0 effect solid`, but that didn't work either. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but any help would be appreciated, especially anyone familiar with the SDK.

Thanks!

Comment: You may benefit more from asking this question [on the forums](https://forum.dji.com/forum.php?mod=forumdisplay&fid=129&filter=typeid&typeid=704), and updating this with an answer if you get one (in the forums)

Answer (score 0):

It’s their firmware issue. I’ve asked DJI for a response and they say new firmware is coming soon.

Did you try entering command mode first.

Does the other type of accessing as in the examples work?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).